# chown not working on ext4 hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, chmod, chown

I have a new 3TB internal hard drive and after writing some data to it I completely zero'd the drive using DD. I then created a partition table (GPT) in Gparted and created an ext4 partition. All went through fine, but the permissions in the drive properties are all set to root and I cant write files to the drive.

Ok, so chown should work right? I tried:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /dev/sdb1
```

with user being my username, but still no difference.

I tried chmod'ing just for good measure:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /dev/sdb1
```

still nothing.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dev/sdb1` is the device file. But the mount point for the hard disk should be somewhere else. For e.g. under `/media/<user>/` or `/mnt/`. Try in the mount point rather than on the device file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the ownership of the device, you need to set the ownership/permissions of the mount point.

Supposing you put the mount point at /data:

```
sudo chown user:user /data
sudo chmod 777 /data
```

This will set the ownership to that user and give everyone permissions to read, write, and execute.

Comment: thanks Theo, it worked, but Kenpachi just beat you to it hence why he got the answered marker :-)